# Give to all circle element onclick beahviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js, onclick

I have to make a function for take all the circle elements and make them clickable. With my code i can click only the last node created and i can't understand why. Can you help me please? I use the d3 library, thats my code:

```
var allCircles = vis.selectAll('circle');

allCircles.on('click', function(){
    /* make the same stuff depending from the circle clicked */
});
```

If you need more explication ask me.

Thank you very much for helping me!`

Comment: Just to make sure, have you checked what `allCircles` actually references multiple elements?

Comment: allCircles is an object with one element, that is an array of all circle created

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to add the event listener on the (parent) container element of the circles instead. This implies that you have such an element, e.g a `<g>` where you can add the listener.

```
var circleContainer = /* find your g element that contains the circles here */;

circleContainer.on('click', function(){
    // d3.event.target is the clicked circle
    d3.select(d3.event.target).attr("fill", "blue");
});
```

If you're more familiar with jQuery the concept is called ['delegated events'](http://api.jquery.com/on/) there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the d3 library and I've never heard of it but I can do it without

```
var circles=document.getElementsByTagName('circle');
function onclik() {
  //do stuff
}
for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
  circles[i].setAttribute("onclick","onclik()")
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: This code is meant to be put inside the SVG file. If you want it to be in the HTML file, replace "document" worth he variable name that holds the SVGDocument object